# Unable to install GDINA on Microsoft R [MRAN] 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, g++, microsoft-r

I am trying to install GDINA on MRAN 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 server and I am getting below error. Please advise how may I do the installation. GDINA is installing on previous version of MRAN and R 4.0.3 on this same machine but failing on MRAN 4.0.2.

```
Microsoft R Open 4.0.2
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2020 Microsoft Corporation

Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 1 cores).

Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2020-07-16.
See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.

* installing *source* package ‘GDINA’ ...
** package ‘GDINA’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
...
. _<removing some g++ compilation outputs>_
g++ -shared -L/opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib -o GDINA.so Lik.o Lik2.o LouisC.o Mord.o Mstep.o NgRg.o RcppExports.o SE.o aggregateCol.o fitstats.o scorep.o sequP.o util.o varsigma.o Microsoft R Open 4.0.2 The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2020 Microsoft Corporation Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 1 cores). Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2020-07-16. See: https://mran.microsoft.com/. -L/opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -L/opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib -lR
g++: error: Microsoft: No such file or directory
g++: error: R: No such file or directory
g++: error: Open: No such file or directory
g++: error: 4.0.2: No such file or directory
...
g++: error: 2020-07-16.: No such file or directory
g++: error: See:: No such file or directory
g++: error: https://mran.microsoft.com/.: No such file or directory
/opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'GDINA.so' failed
make: *** [GDINA.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘GDINA’
* removing ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/GDINA’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘GDINA’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpTrbkOd/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: judging by how soon along it failed, I'd check permissions. Have your tried cloning and building locally, R CMD style?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Actually, I couldn't mention all the error logs here because stackoverflow restricted me saying something like "a lot of code and not enough text". But, while installation a lot of dependencies required for GDINA got installed and then failed while installing GDINA. But on this same machine, GDINA installs on R 4.0.3. Issue is when I install GDINA on MRAN 4.0.2. I'll try to see how to build locally using R CMD, haven't done that before.